# WPF change cursor for TabControl header text in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have tried the following below but it always ends up setting the cursor for all of the elements instead of just the TabControl header text.

```
<TabControl Cursor="Hand"></TabControl>
<TabItem Cursor="Hand"></TabItem>
```

Thinking I might have to override some template of some sort?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining the structure of the header and assigning the cursor pointer to that:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Header goes here..." Cursor="Hand" />
    </TabItem.Header>
    <Label Content="Content goes here..." />
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Cursor needs to be on the `TextBlock`, when it is on the `TabItem.Header` I am getting the error: `Cannot set properties on property elements`.  Other than that this works great.  Update your answer and I will accept it.  Any chance you know how to keep the current styles on the `TabItem.Header` when overriding the template? I am using MahApps.Metro and the nice styles disappear.

Comment: edited the answer - makes sense, I didn't actually test it before I posted haha.  Unfortunately I don't know how to maintain the style when overriding the template, it's been a looooong time since I wrote any WPF haha

Comment: For sure, appreciate the help.